# Вынести данные за пределы запроса?

Tags: android, вконтакте

Имеется запрос,который запрашивает список id всех друзей, в итоге получается массив ids. Как его вынести за пределы, если просто приравнивать, то ничего сработает.Заранее спасибо

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.COUNT, 
10));
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            VKApiModel vkApiModel = (VKApiModel) response.parsedModel;
            ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONObject object = response.json;
            try {
                JSONObject objectResponse = object.getJSONObject("response");
                JSONArray jsonArray = objectResponse.getJSONArray("items");

                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    ids.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы каждый объявляете новый массив кодом:

> ```
>         ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

Вам необходимо создать специальный класс, который будет является хранилищем, как правило, для этого используют паттерн Repository http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/repository.html. Google рекомендует примерно такое использование https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#fetching_data